# Is the sum of windowed sinusoids equal a single windowed sinusoid?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, signal-processing

I am working on a signal processing problem which requires some property to be true, and now I am not even sure if it is true or not. I appreciate help in finding the proof/disproof for the property.

**Problem setup**

Suppose we have a sum of $K$ sinusoidal signals, where I represent them in the complex domain:
$$r[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{K-1} \widetilde{\alpha}_k g[n - \tau_k] \exp[j2\pi \omega n - j2\pi\tau_k]$$

$\widetilde{\alpha}_k$ is the amplitude and phase of the $k^{th}$ sinusoid,

$g[n]$ is some window function in discrete time with $n$ the discrete time value $n \in \{0...N-1\}$.

$\tau_k$ is the time delay for the $k^{th}$ sinusoid.

**Required Proof**

I need to find out whether or not $r[n]$ can be represented as:

$$r[n] = \tilde{\beta} h[n] \exp[j2\pi\omega n]$$

That is, in words: is the sum of windowed sinusoids with different amplitudes, phases and time delays equal to one sinusoid with some amplitude $\tilde{\beta}$ and arbitrary window function $h[n]$?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Take $\sin(x)$ and $\cos x$, and window $\cos x$ on $[-2 \pi,0]$ using a rectangular window and $\sin x$ on $[0, 2 \pi]$.

There isn't a $h(x)$ such that the construction above is of the form $A h(x) \sin(x+\phi)$ for some non-negative $h(x)$.

Comment: See my answer, in signal processing we mean complex sines ${}$

Comment: @user1952009 - (1) Your answer doesn't use the usual definition of window -- if you allow $h$ to be arbitrary, then its obvious the statement is true, but you wouldn't call $h$ a window.  (2) you can trivially write a real sinusoid as a sum of 2 complex sinusoids. but that doesn't matter here -- its a counterexample.

Comment: If you knew the usual definition of a window (concentrated in time and frequency) you would know that in signal processing we mean complex sines

Comment: Of course what I answered is what matter here : it shows we need to look at the spectrum of $W(n) = w \ast \sum_k A_k \delta(n-t_k)$. For small $K$ it will stay "a (complex) window" if $w(n)$ was a window.

Answer (score 0):

$$x(n) = \sum_{k=1}^K A_k e^{i \omega n} w(n-t_k) = e^{i \omega n} (\sum_{k=1}^K A_k  w(n-t_k)) = e^{i \omega n} W(n)$$

So yes if you allow the window $W(n) = \sum_{k=1}^K A_k w(n-t_k)$ to be complex valued.

If $w(n)$ is band-limited then $W(n)$ will be band-limited too.
But if it is finitely supported, it is only $\epsilon$-approximatively band limited, and $W(n)$ will be $K\epsilon$-approximatively band limited.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to factor $W(n)$ into a complex valued amplitude, and a real-valued windowed function. Would it be possible to factor the sum like that? $\sum_{k=1}^K A_k w(n-t_k) = A w'(n)$? where $w'(n)$ is a real valued function.

Comment: @GergesDib No.Try with an example ${}$